# send data with a redirect

Tags: javascript, php, json, laravel

i'm implementing card payments in my app, when a payment is approved or rejected it redirects to a URL

**I need when redirecting to send the variable 'status' 'status detail' 'id' to the controller**

[image]

```
     <script>
       const cardForm = mp.cardForm({
  amount: "100.5",
  autoMount: true,
  form: {
    id: "form-checkout",
    cardholderName: {
      id: "form-checkout__cardholderName",
      placeholder: "Nombre",
    },
    cardholderEmail: {
      id: "form-checkout__cardholderEmail",
      placeholder: "E-mail",
    },
    cardNumber: {
      id: "form-checkout__cardNumber",
      placeholder: "Número de la tarjeta",
    },
    expirationDate: {
      id: "form-checkout__expirationDate",
      placeholder: "MM/YY",
    },
    securityCode: {
      id: "form-checkout__securityCode",
      placeholder: "000",
    },
    installments: {
      id: "form-checkout__installments",
      placeholder: "Cuotas",
    },
    identificationType: {
      id: "form-checkout__identificationType",
      placeholder: "Tipo de documento",
    },
    identificationNumber: {
      id: "form-checkout__identificationNumber",
      placeholder: "Número de documento",
    },
    issuer: {
      id: "form-checkout__issuer",
      placeholder: "Banco emisor",
    },
  },
  callbacks: {
    onFormMounted: error => {
      if (error) return console.warn("Form Mounted handling error: ", error);
      console.log("Form mounted");
    },
    onSubmit: event => {
      event.preventDefault();

      const {
        paymentMethodId: payment_method_id,
        issuerId: issuer_id,
        cardholderEmail: email,
        amount,
        token,
        installments,
        identificationNumber,
        identificationType,
      } = cardForm.getCardFormData();

      fetch("/process_payment", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          token,
          issuer_id,
          payment_method_id,
          transaction_amount: Number(amount),
          installments: Number(installments),
          description: "Descripción del producto",
          payer: {
            email,
            identification: {
              type: identificationType,
              number: identificationNumber,
            },
                        },
                    }),
                })
                    .then(response => {
                        return response.json();
                    })
                    .then(result => {
if(result.status == "approved"){

window.location.href = "/thanks";

}else{
  window.location.href = "/rejected";
}
})
                    .catch(error => {
                        alert("Unexpected error\n"+JSON.stringify(error));
                    });
            },
    onFetching: (resource) => {
      console.log("Fetching resource: ", resource);

      // Animate progress bar
      const progressBar = document.querySelector(".progress-bar");
      progressBar.removeAttribute("value");

      return () => {
        progressBar.setAttribute("value", "0");
      };
    }
  },
});
   </script>
```

i don't have much knowledge with js, so far the process is correct but I need to redirect and pass the data

How can I pass that data with js? help please.

Comment: Redirect can only be a GET request

Comment: Usually payment platforms such as stripe, just return success or failure and no other payment details in the JS response. You can configure a webhook and they will POST the fulfilled order event to your backend which you can then obtain sole details of the completed purchase and store it in your DB. This is much more secure because it's all done ok the backend. Maybe your library also has such a feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply you can pass details using query string to the url or just call ajax
like this way

```
window.location.href = "/thanks?status="+result.status+"&id="+result.id;
```

or using ajax

```
                $.ajax({
                        headers: {
                            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                        },
                        url: "{{url('/thanks')}}",
                        type: "POST",
                        data:  {"id" : result.id,"status":result.status},
                        success: function(data){
                            console.log("ajax called succesfully");
                        }

                    });
```

Comment: Both approaches are not optimal, because with post and ajax user could manually forge requests. With get the same issue. It's a vulnerability issue especially dealing with transaction data that might get stored on the backend to validate payment.

Comment: Even if you are using csrf token user can still post multiple requests using the same crsf token.

Answer (score 0):

You should not be storing payment transaction details using ajax or GET. This is insecure and very vulnerable to being exploited.

I suppose you use the transaction info on the backed, such as `approved` or `accredited` to offer some goods or service to the customer. I could easily POST using ajax or forge the GET request and fake a transaction that you would store on your backend. I could then receive the service for free.

You need to validate payment on the backend. So your payment provider should have some webhook where they POST the transaction details to your API, you only allow them to post to that API. Then you store those details in your DB and fulfill the order.

Another approach is to encrypt the form details and send it to your backend, then from your backend you post it to the payment provider, and they respond through the backend. The reason it has to be encrypted on the frontend is that credit card info should never touch your servers because it's a big security issue. The encryption JS is usually provided by the payment provider/merchant.

Try to check if your paycheck provider offers some alternatives, such as a webhook or an encryption JS for your forms.

Comment: I understand, but the data that I need to pass is not for validation, it is only for information to the client (inovice).  how would I do it without passing parameters by URL?

Comment: If you vare certain you will never use that data for validation a purchase now or in the future, then it might be ok. However I would still recommend against this, because you are storing payment transaction information in your DB based on unvalidated request. In the future you might suddenly decided to use that data for validation without noticing it's corrupt. Even creating some financial report for example. If possible try to investigate if the library offers alternatives, such as using webhooks or encrypting the form and submitting to your backend.